# Page resources fail to load when removing '/' slash from URL upon .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a simple redirect rule as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^contact-us\/?.*$ ./contact-us.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

This rule works fine for the following URL:

```
http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/contact-us/
```

The problem is that if I remove the final slash, the page loads properly but the resources (css/js) are not loading

```
http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/contact-us ----> This fails
```

It seems it is omitting a folder when trying to load the resources so rather than `http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/js/jquery.js`, the URL for the JS resource is being set as `http://localhost/folder1/folder2/js/jquery.js`

Is there a concept missing here with the rules? How to make both URLs work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to your use of relative paths in js/css etc.

To fix, you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/folder1/folder2/folder3/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: You are right, I am using relative paths for resources. But how does this get affected when the slash is not in the URL? Besides, the base tag did not fix the issue.

Comment: It worked, I didnt update my sources at first... THanksss... But can you please explain what happened

Comment: Taking an example. If trailing `/` is not there on a page that is `http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder3/contact-us` then `"../style.css" will be resolved as `http://localhost/folder1/folder2/style.css` which will return in 404. With `base` tag it will correctly prefix base URL before any relative URL.